# Is there a way to fill the first name with the full name?

Tags: sql

I am currently practicing my SQL skills. I have a table like this:

| name | target_type |
| --- | --- |
| PoM-Blessy | Department |
| Blessy Marie Oxford | User |
| PoM-Alfred | Department |
| PoM-Freddy | Department |
| Freddy Friedman | User |
| Alfred Stallone | User |

What I want to achieve is a result that looks like this:

| name | target_type | full_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PoM-Blessy | Department | Blessy Marie Oxford |
| Blessy Marie Oxford | User | Blessy Marie Oxford |
| PoM-Alfred | Department | Alfred Stallone |
| PoM-Freddy | Department | Freddy Friedman |
| Freddy Friedman | User | Freddy Friedman |
| Alfred Stallone | User | Alfred Stallone |

Note: PoM is a property manager. Each PoM has been assigned to a specific user. The goal is as long as it contains a partial of a specific name in PoM, it would try to vlookup (Excel) the name column that has a full name of it.

Is there a way how can I achieve this? I tried different solutions on my own but I can't find a logic. It would be appreciate if someone can help me thanks. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here;  please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample table data, and also adjust the expected result.

Comment: Adding on, when you edit, specifically describe **why** is "PoM-Blessy" related to "Blessy Marie Oxford" . Is it just because the text after the hyphen matches the text up until the first whitespace character in "Blessy Marie Oxford". Is that a hard and fast rule?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: an English (not code) explanation of the logic that you want to implement - how does `PoM-Blessy` relate to `Blessy Marie Oxford`? If you cannot explain that using English then there is no way to implement it in code.

Comment: That first table looks suspiciously like you're going down the [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model) route, which for most database applications would be an anti-pattern.

Comment: The short answer is no, not with the data provided.  It looks like you want records with department to have the full name of a different (user) record; but you provide no mechanism to associate the user and department in the data.  For example: PoM-Freddy we assume associates to Freddy Friedman based on expected results, but what if there was a Freddy Mac.  How would we know which one to choose?  There's not a unique key which can be used to combine these two and as such any attempt would likely break once a duplicate name is encountered.

Comment: This isn't to say what you're asking for can't be done, we're saying you shouldn't do it because it will likely fail the first time it encounters a duplicate (POM) name as a first name.  Lets extend your data to have a user called "Freddy Mac" and a department called "PoM-Freddy" tell us what you expect their full name to be on the department record and how the system would know which freddy to pick?  Also can you guarantee for each POM-Name, there is an associated user and vice versa?

Comment: What does `select version();`, `select @@version;` or `select * from V$VERSION;` return?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server though the approach should work in most RDBMS systems.

The lack of a "Concrete/Formal" association between user/department is the crux of the problem and will lead to more problems as more data is added; especially users with the same first name.

However, if you must: but this breaks the moment you have more than 1 person with the same first name... as in this [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/JBnG_WQl) with freddy mac user.

I suppose we could use SQL recursion and process record by record and add a row number to each to manage it; but this would have its own problems as it assumes the assocation of records rather than being told. It would cause problems as more columns are added to the table which must be related accuratly for the user/department.

Again to be clear: this works so long as user first name and POM Value  are unique.  THe second they aren't this breaks.  ***I DO NOT recommend you continue on this path until you address the lack of concrete assocation between the two records (user and department).***  However if you can guarantee first name uniqueness with the department PoM-FirstName, then this will work.

[DB Fiddle Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/IzT7RuD-)

```
--Generate a CTE with the sampe data (later on substitute CTE 
--in the two unions below with your tablename.

With CTE AS(
SELECT 'PoM-Blessy' name,   'Department' target_type UNION ALL
SELECT 'Blessy Marie Oxford',   'User'UNION ALL
SELECT 'PoM-Alfred',    'Department'UNION ALL
SELECT 'PoM-Freddy',    'Department'UNION ALL
SELECT 'Freddy Friedman',   'User' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alfred Stallone',   'User')

--GET All the users with their full name
SELECT name, target_Type, name as full_name
FROM CTE 
WHERE target_Type = 'user'
UNION

--Union the department records "Lookup" the full name using 
--a coorlated subquery.  Note we use the A.Name from the outer
--query as the filter on the inner query which is limited to just 
--users.

SELECT A.name, A.target_Type, (Select name 
                           from cte B
                          where B.name like concat(replace(A.name,'PoM-',''),'%') 
                            and B.target_Type='User')
FROM CTE A
WHERE A.Target_Type = 'department'
```

RESULT:

```
+---------------------+-------------+---------------------+
|        name         | target_Type |      full_name      |
+---------------------+-------------+---------------------+
| Blessy Marie Oxford | User        | Blessy Marie Oxford |
| Freddy Friedman     | User        | Freddy Friedman     |
| Alfred Stallone     | User        | Alfred Stallone     |
| PoM-Blessy          | Department  | Blessy Marie Oxford |
| PoM-Alfred          | Department  | Alfred Stallone     |
| PoM-Freddy          | Department  | Freddy Friedman     |
+---------------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

**EXPLAINED:**

- The CTE is to just generate the sample data to work wtih
- We write two queries.  The first just gives us all the users and their full name
- we union in the second query which is for the departments and we use coorlation to lookup the matching first name based on us eliminating the 'POM-' from the department name.
- By using the replace function, we eliminte the ability to index this so it isn't likely performant on large scale.

**BETTER APPROACH:**

Would be to operate based on a unique ID field which relates the user to the department and then a simple self join could be used to get the full name of the department PoMs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning SQL and decided to try this as a challenge. Tried a different approach using subqueries that create 2 temporary tables. Created a name_id field as an ID to link User and Department names then used JOIN to "vlookup" the name column. You still have the problem of users having the same first name since they would have the same name_id. Tested on BigQuery.

```
SELECT
  name, target_type, table2.full_name AS full_name

FROM
  (
  SELECT name, target_type,
  CASE
  WHEN target_type = "Department"
  THEN SUBSTR(name, STRPOS(name, "-") +1)
  ELSE SUBSTR(name, 1, STRPOS(name, " ") -1)
  END AS name_id
  FROM `Your_table_location`
  ) AS table1 /*complete table with name_id field*/

INNER JOIN 
  (
  SELECT name as full_name, SUBSTR(name, 1, STRPOS(name, " ") -1) AS name_id
  FROM `Your_table_location`
  WHERE target_type = "User"
  ) AS table2 /*this table serves as a reference table*/

ON table1.name_id = table2.name_id

ORDER BY full_name /*optional*/
```